# Buffer overrun in ATL COM dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, com, atl

I am trying to create a COM dll using ATL that matches another one I had originally had in C#.  This dll is normally called by a third party dll that I do not have the source code for so I wanted the UUIDs to be the same as well as the progID.  I also have a test application that calls methods in my dll and that is how I have been testing it.  The interface defined by the test application is:

```
STDMETHOD(GetSwitchCriteria)(double* intensity, double* minMass, double* maxMass, 
    BOOL* selectIntensity, long* numOfDepCycles) = 0;
STDMETHOD(GetChargeStateParam)(short* minCharge, short* maxCharge, BOOL* doChargeState) = 0;
STDMETHOD(GetInclusionList)(double* intensity, double* theList, short* numOfItems) = 0;
STDMETHOD(GetExclusionList)(long* exRTWindow, double* theMassList, long* theRTList, 
    short* numOfItems) = 0;
STDMETHOD(GetOtherCriteria)(long* smartFilterTime, double* isoExclusionWin,
    double* massTolerance, BOOL* isPPM) = 0;
STDMETHOD(GetIsotopeMatchParam)(double* theMassList, double* theAbundanceList,
    short* numOfItems, double* abTolerance, double* maTolerance) = 0;

// called at the start of each IDA run
STDMETHOD(OnInitIDA)() = 0;
// called at the end of each survey scan
STDMETHOD(OnScreenSurveySpec)() = 0;
// called at the time of switch
STDMETHOD(OnPrepareNextScan)(double* selectedMasses, double* selectedIntensities, long* selectedCharges, int itemCount) = 0;
```

In my new dll using ATL I tried to mimic this and the definitions are below:

```
STDMETHOD(GetSwitchCriteria)(DOUBLE* intensity, DOUBLE* minMass, DOUBLE* maxMass, VARIANT_BOOL* selectIntensity, LONG* numOfDepCycles);
STDMETHOD(GetChargeStateParam)(SHORT* minCharge, SHORT* maxCharge, VARIANT_BOOL* doChargeState);
STDMETHOD(GetInclusionList)(DOUBLE* intensity, DOUBLE* theList, SHORT* numOfItems);
STDMETHOD(GetExclusionList)(LONG* exRTWindow, DOUBLE* theMassList, LONG* theRTList, SHORT* numOfItems);
STDMETHOD(GetOtherCriteria)(LONG* smartFilterTime, DOUBLE* isoExclusionWin, DOUBLE* massTolerance, VARIANT_BOOL* isPPM);
STDMETHOD(GetIsotopeMatchParam)(DOUBLE* theMassList, DOUBLE* theAbundanceList, DOUBLE* abTolerance, DOUBLE* maTolerance);
STDMETHOD(OnInitIDA)(void);
STDMETHOD(OnScreenSurveySpec)(void);
STDMETHOD(OnPrepareNextScan)(DOUBLE* selectedMasses, DOUBLE* selectedIntensities, LONG* selectedCharges, LONG itemCount);
```

Originally I had used BOOL for some of the parameters but I noticed that the C# dll used VARIANT_BOOL when I looked in the TLB file for it.

When I call the two methods that have no parameters I get an HRESULT of 0.  The same does for the OnPrepareNextScan method.  However when I call the others I get an exception, a buffer overrun and I am not sure why this is the case.  Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or how I can investigate this?

Is this likely due to a type incompatibility between the types defined in both interfaces and possibly the types I use when creating the variables for use with the method?  An example of the code used to call one of the methods is:

```
short minCharge = 0;
short maxCharge = 0;
BOOL doChargeState = FALSE;

result = m_pUserIDA->GetChargeStateParam(&minCharge, &maxCharge, &doChargeState);
    std::cout << "HRESULT of GetChargeStateParam: " << result << std::endl;
```

Tried the LONGLONG solution mentioned below but it did not seem to help.

I thought I should post the original interface from the C# dll.

```
[Guid("76F452FF-7A89-11d4-8A2C-00B0D023C6A0")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public unsafe interface IUserIDA
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void GetSwitchCriteria(ref double intensity, ref double minMass, ref double maxMass, ref bool selectIntensity, ref long numOfDepCycles);

    [DispId(2)]
    void GetChargeStateParam(ref short minCharge, ref short maxCharge, ref bool doChargeState);

    [DispId(3)]
    void GetInclusionList(ref double intensity, ref double theList, ref short numOfItems);

    [DispId(4)]
    void GetExclusionList(ref long exRTWindow, ref double theMassList, ref long theRTList, ref short numOfItems);

    [DispId(5)]
    void GetOtherCriteria(ref long smartFilterTime, ref double isoExclusionWin, ref double massTolerance, ref bool isPPM);

    [DispId(6)]
    void GetIsotopeMatchParam(ref double theMassList, ref double theAbundanceList, ref short numOfItems, ref  double abTolerance, ref double maTolerance);

    [DispId(7)]
    void OnInitIDA();

    [DispId(8)]
    void OnScreenSurveySpec();

    [DispId(9)]
    void OnPrepareNextScan(double* selectedMasses, double* SelectedIntensities, long* selectedCharges, int itemCount);
}
```

The last method, OnPrepareNextScan is the only one that seems to work, and you can see it is definted using normal pointers rather than .NET ref statements, could this be a problem?

I thought I might also include the Type Lib files for each, perhaps a difference in those will make it clear what the problem is and any differences between the two:

The original C# dll:

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: AnalystIDA.dll

[
 uuid(7ED40FB0-D178-47FA-9EF3-B434E0803D5F),
 version(1.0),
 custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D, "Analyst_UserIDA, Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de4cf4f15e545467")

]
library Analyst_UserIDA
{
// TLib :     // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
// TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
importlib("stdole2.tlb");

// Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
interface IUserIDA;
interface _Utility;

[
  uuid(CDD947DD-7B9E-382E-9F6F-55218F927C3A),
  version(1.0),
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "Analyst_UserIDA.Utility")
]
coclass Utility {
    [default] interface _Utility;
    interface _Object;
};

[
  odl,
  uuid(76F452FF-7A89-11D4-8A2C-00B0D023C6A0),
  version(1.0),
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "Analyst_UserIDA.IUserIDA")    

]
interface IUserIDA : IUnknown {
    HRESULT _stdcall GetSwitchCriteria(
                    [in, out] double* intensity, 
                    [in, out] double* minMass, 
                    [in, out] double* maxMass, 
                    [in, out] VARIANT_BOOL* selectIntensity, 
                    [in, out] int64* numOfDepCycles);
    HRESULT _stdcall GetChargeStateParam(
                    [in, out] short* minCharge, 
                    [in, out] short* maxCharge, 
                    [in, out] VARIANT_BOOL* doChargeState);
    HRESULT _stdcall GetInclusionList(
                    [in, out] double* intensity, 
                    [in, out] double* theList, 
                    [in, out] short* numOfItems);
    HRESULT _stdcall GetExclusionList(
                    [in, out] int64* exRTWindow, 
                    [in, out] double* theMassList, 
                    [in, out] int64* theRTList, 
                    [in, out] short* numOfItems);
    HRESULT _stdcall GetOtherCriteria(
                    [in, out] int64* smartFilterTime, 
                    [in, out] double* isoExclusionWin, 
                    [in, out] double* massTolerance, 
                    [in, out] VARIANT_BOOL* isPPM);
    HRESULT _stdcall GetIsotopeMatchParam(
                    [in, out] double* theMassList, 
                    [in, out] double* theAbundanceList, 
                    [in, out] short* numOfItems, 
                    [in, out] double* abTolerance, 
                    [in, out] double* maTolerance);
    HRESULT _stdcall OnInitIDA();
    HRESULT _stdcall OnScreenSurveySpec();
    HRESULT _stdcall OnPrepareNextScan(
                    [in, out] double* selectedMasses, 
                    [in, out] double* SelectedIntensities, 
                    [in, out] int64* selectedCharges, 
                    [in] long itemCount);
};

[
  uuid(5B2DBDD4-B763-428A-B48F-2E148138E7A4),
  version(1.0),
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "Analyst_UserIDA.UserIDAObject")
]
coclass UserIDAObject {
    interface _Object;
    [default] interface IUserIDA;
};

[
  odl,
  uuid(8094073C-362D-37BB-9791-E9D163271C73),
  hidden,
  dual,
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "Analyst_UserIDA.Utility")    

]
interface _Utility : IDispatch {
};
};
```

My new dll:

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: AnalystIDA.dll

[
 uuid(7ED40FB0-D178-47FA-9EF3-B434E0803D5F),
 version(1.0),
 helpstring("AnalystIDA 1.0 Type Library"),
 custom(DE77BA64-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 117441012),
 custom(DE77BA63-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 1329510523),
 custom(DE77BA65-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, "Created by MIDL version 7.00.0500 at  Fri     Feb 17 15:28:38 2012
")

]
library AnalystIDALib
{
// TLib :     // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
importlib("stdole2.tlb");

// Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
interface IUserIDA;

[
  uuid(5B2DBDD4-B763-428A-B48F-2E148138E7A4),
  helpstring("UserIDAObject Class")
]
coclass UserIDAObject {
    [default] interface IUserIDA;
};

[
  odl,
  uuid(76F452FF-7A89-11D4-8A2C-00B0D023C6A0),
  helpstring("IUserIDA Interface"),
  dual,
  nonextensible,
  oleautomation
]
interface IUserIDA : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), helpstring("method GetSwitchCriteria")]
    HRESULT GetSwitchCriteria(
                    [in, out] double* intensity, 
                    [in, out] double* minMass, 
                    [in, out] double* maxMass, 
                    [in, out] VARIANT_BOOL* selectIntensity, 
                    [in, out] long* numOfDepCycles);
    [id(0x00000002), helpstring("method GetChargeStateParam")]
    HRESULT GetChargeStateParam(
                    [in, out] short* minCharge, 
                    [in, out] short* maxCharge, 
                    [in, out] VARIANT_BOOL* doChargeState);
    [id(0x00000003), helpstring("method GetInclusionList")]
    HRESULT GetInclusionList(
                    [in, out] double* intensity, 
                    [in, out] double* theList, 
                    [in, out] short* numOfItems);
    [id(0x00000004), helpstring("method GetExclusionList")]
    HRESULT GetExclusionList(
                    [in, out] long* exRTWindow, 
                    [in, out] double* theMassList, 
                    [in, out] long* theRTList, 
                    [in, out] short* numOfItems);
    [id(0x00000005), helpstring("method GetOtherCriteria")]
    HRESULT GetOtherCriteria(
                    [in, out] long* smartFilterTime, 
                    [in, out] double* isoExclusionWin, 
                    [in, out] double* massTolerance, 
                    [in, out] VARIANT_BOOL* isPPM);
    [id(0x00000006), helpstring("method GetIsotopeMatchParam")]
    HRESULT GetIsotopeMatchParam(
                    [in, out] double* theMassList, 
                    [in, out] double* theAbundanceList, 
                    [in, out] double* abTolerance, 
                    [in, out] double* maTolerance);
    [id(0x00000007), helpstring("method OnInitIDA")]
    HRESULT OnInitIDA();
    [id(0x00000008), helpstring("method OnScreenSurveySpec")]
    HRESULT OnScreenSurveySpec();
    [id(0x00000009), helpstring("method OnPrepareNextScan")]
    HRESULT OnPrepareNextScan(
                    [in, out] double* selectedMasses, 
                    [in, out] double* selectedIntensities, 
                    [in, out] long* selectedCharges, 
                    [in] long itemCount);
};
};
```

**Another Edit:**
I notice that the ProgID Analyst_UserIDA.UserIDAObject does not appear in my new dll's type lib.  This is used in order to create an instance of the UserIDAObject in the test application:
    IUserIDAPtr m_pUserIDA; 
    ::CoInitialize(m_pUserIDA);
    m_pUserIDA.CreateInstance(_T("Analyst_UserIDA.UserIDAObject"));

**More progress/confusion:**
I decided to see if there was a problem with the DLL by creating a C# project that would call this dll.  When  I did this the methods I have a problem with work.  I have also noticed that the methods that appeared to work originally do not.  I added a sleep statement to one of them and it never appears to be executed when called by my test application.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Win32 a `LONG` is a 32-bit integer, while in C# a `long` is a 64-bit integer. That may cause the problems that you describe.

The solution is to use a `__int64` or a `LONGLONG` whenever C# uses a `long`.

Comment: I will give that a try.  I was looking this up but I found rather inconsistent answers and was a bit confused.